# Permission Issue when moving data from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script that moves a range of data from one spreadsheet to another. I'm running into a permission issue when I try to open the destination spreadsheet, I keep getting the error "You do not have permission to call open." I've tried open(file), openByUrl(url), and openById(id), and all three methods raise that same error.

I am the owner of the destination spreadsheet, so I don't understand why I don't have permission. I am also the owner of the script, and I have read/write access to the source spreadsheet (although I am not the owner).

Thanks for your help.

Here's my code:

```
function moveData() {
   var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1kfELXf9WxcZGsUO0piCjEXC_-ZR57GvbFzx1UPw89K4");

   ...
}
```

Comment: Is the destination spreadsheet in a different Google account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately [this behaviour is prohibited by Google](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5174#c6): Following an update to Apps Script rolled out last June, custom functions are permitted to read data only from the current spreadsheet.

Their recommendation is to use [the IMPORTRANGE formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) instead.